# Sorting an array from smallest to largest in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array according to [example 104.5](http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-6?noredirect=1). It asks you to sort an array from smallest to largest. I've thoroughly scoured through my program several times, but I can't spot my error. Here's the code from my sorting class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Sorting {
    public static int smallest(int[] array) {
        int min = array[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < array[0]) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallest(int[] array) {
        int ind = array[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < array[0]) {
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        int ind = index;
        for(int i = index; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < array[index]) {
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int stor = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = stor;
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        int indSmall;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            indSmall = indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(array, i);
            swap(array, indSmall, i);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code I am running:

```
int[] values = {8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4};
        Sorting.sort(values);
```

It should output:

```
[8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

But instead it is outputting:

```
[8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4]
[4, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8]
[4, 2, 7, 9, 1, 3, 8]
[4, 2, 3, 9, 1, 7, 8]
[4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 7, 9]
[4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 7, 9]
[4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 7, 9]
[4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if(array[i] < array[0]) {
```

should be

```
if(array[i] < min) {
```

**or** you could use [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) like

```
min = Math.min(array[i], min);
```

without an `if` at all.

**Also**, in `indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom`

```
if(array[i] < array[index]) {
```

should be

```
if(array[i] < array[ind]) {
```

Comment: Only _indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom_ and _swap_ are called. The methods that use the `if(array[i] < array[0])` comparison are never called, so that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: @Rob Then why are they in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if I should have posted the class in its entirety or posted just the relevant methods. I'll do the latter next time.

Comment: @Rob Edited to point out *basically* the same bug in `indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom`.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you.